# segmentation fault extending psycopg2._psycopg.cursor

Tags: python, psycopg2

This small code snippet results in SIGSEGV (I thought this wouldn't be possible in a language with garbage collection like python, but I'm used to be an ace in creating new kind of bugs) even though the database exists and the connection works, anyway I was trying to extend psycopg2._psycopg.cursor class to have a function returning query results in dictionary form, what am I doing wrong?

```
import psycopg2

class dcursor(psycopg2._psycopg.cursor):
    def __init__(self,parent_cursor):
        self=parent_cursor
    def dictfetchall(self): 
        "Returns all rows from a cursor as a dict" 
        desc = cursor.description 
        return [
                dict(zip([col[0] for col in desc], row)) 
                for row in cursor.fetchall() 
        ]

conn = psycopg2.connect("dbname=dbpgs user=openerp")
cur = dcursor(conn.cursor())
cur.execute('select name_related from hr_employee;')
print cur.dictfetchall()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cursor signature takes a connection as first argument. The way you have overridden `__init__` makes it take a cursor. Segfault follows. Your class is more a wrapper than a cursor. You are also not calling the `__init__` base class, and `self=parent_cursor` doesn't do anything.

The right way to subclass a cursor taking your example is something like:

```
class dcursor(psycopg2.extensions.cursor):
    def dictfetchall(self): 
        "Returns all rows from a cursor as a dict" 
        desc = self.description 
        return [
                dict(zip([col[0] for col in desc], row)) 
                for row in self.fetchall() 
        ]

conn = psycopg2.connect("dbname=dbpgs user=openerp")
cur = conn.cursor(cursor_factory=dcursor)
cur.execute('select name_related from hr_employee;')
print cur.dictfetchall()
```

but see also fog's suggestion about using `DictCursor`.

Answer (score 0):

It *is* possible, because `psycopg2` is a module written in C, it only exposes its API to Python. You can see the code here: http://github.com/psycopg/psycopg2.git

I guess what you've encountered is a bug in Psycopg. That said, underscore in the `_psycopg` package name indicates, that classes defined there are not really meant to be subclassed.

Why don't you define `dictfetchall()` as a standalone helper function? It doesn't access any internal state of the cursor object, there's no real need to make it a cursor method.

Comment: I need dictfetchall() to be a method of cursor since i have plenty of code in openerp which uses cursor.dictfetchall, but I wasn't able to find out what kind of cursor is called there so I was trying to reimplement it easily

Comment: Psycopg cursors are subclassable OK, they just need to be subclassed the right way (e.g. calling their `__init__` and passing it the right params).

Comment: Indeed - I overlooked lack of super constructor call, my bad! Still, I'd expect it to fail in a more graceful way than `SIGSEGV` :)

Comment: It's a failure mode I hadn't expected: not calling the superclass c'tor is a pretty fundamental python error. If it's not too difficult I'll think about adding a guard about this poor usage.

Comment: Added bad cursor subclass guard: to be released in psycopg 2.5.3

Comment: Thanks, that's the spirit!

Answer (score 0):

psycopg2 is written in C and unless you know what you're doing it is possible to cause a SIGSEGV when calling/extending the module. All common functions and method carefully check their arguments both to avoid breakage and security problems but there are areas where, right now, the burden of doing the Right Thing is on the client code. You just hit one of those areas: extending the connection or cursor types.

To do this right you need to do some specific work in your `__init__` method, as shown here:

https://github.com/psycopg/psycopg2/blob/master/lib/extras.py#L49

Specifically `cursor` (and `connection`) are new-style classes and need to be initialized using `super()` and the full list of parameters passed to `__init__`. At minimum:

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(DictCursorBase, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

I linked that example specifically because it already does what you need, i.e., fetches data and makes it available as `dict`s. Just `import psycopg.extras.DictCursor` (to use a `dict`-like row class) or `import psycopg.extras.RealDictCursor` (to use a real `dict` for every row) and you're done.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error and the solution was to replace the psycopg2 with a different version. I replaced 2.6 version for 2.4 version and the problem was fixed.

You can validate this by running python interpreter and importing psycopg2.

[image]